# The lattice $(E (X) , \subseteq,\cap ,\vee)$ of equivalences on a set $X$ is semimodular

Tags: lattice-orders

- Consider two element in a lattice $L$ says a and b. we say that a covers b and write $a \succ b$ if $a > b$ and if there is no x in L such that $a > x > b$.
- A lattice is  said be Semmimodular if for all a,b in L, $a \succ a \wedge b$ and $b \succ a \wedge b$ $\Rightarrow a \vee b \succ a$ and $a \vee b \succ b$

we know that $ \rho \wedge \sigma = \rho \cap \sigma $ for any $\rho, \sigma \in E(X)$.

Let $\rho , \sigma$ be equivalences on $X$ such that  $\rho \succ \rho \wedge \sigma$ and $\sigma \succ \rho \wedge \sigma$

therefore  $\rho \succ \rho \cap \sigma$ and $\sigma \succ \rho \cap \sigma$

Suppose that $\rho \cap \sigma $ classes are $A_1, A_2 , \cdots $

> > I want to prove that exactly one $\rho -$ class that is the union of two $\rho \cap \sigma$ classes and other $\rho$ and $\rho \cap \sigma$ classes  are same .
> >
> > I mean that $\rho$ classes of the form $A_1 \cup A_2 , A_3 , A_4 , \cdots $

Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier if you use the following definition of semi-modular lattice:
$\mathbf{L}$ is semi-modular if for every $a, b, c \in L$,
$$a \prec b \Rightarrow a \vee c \preceq b \vee c.$$
Then, I suppose you know that in the lattice of partitions of a set, $\rho \prec \sigma$ if $\sigma$ results from $\rho$ by uniting two of its blocks.

Now, given that characterization of the cover relations, if $\rho, \sigma, \pi$ are partitions (equivalent relations) of a set, if $\rho \prec \sigma$, then either $\rho \vee \pi = \sigma \vee \pi$ (if in $\pi$ there are elements of both of those blocks of $\rho$, so that those blocks are also united in $\rho \vee \pi$) or $\rho \vee \pi \prec \sigma \vee \pi$, so that $a \vee c \preceq b \vee c$.

Comment: Sir I am beigner in the semigroup theory, so I have no idea of blocks. I am studying the book 'Fundamentals of Semigroup theory' by John M. Howie . I am unable to understand this step

Comment: Blocks are the same as equivalence classes. It is usual to call them blocks when we think of them as partitions, and as classes when we think of them as equivalence relations. Equivalence relations and partitions are essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks  for the prompt reply